# 12.10: Webcam stopped working after update

Tags: webcam

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits, on a Lenovo Ideapad U410. I've been using the included webcam with Skype and Google Hangout with no issues. At some point in time, I noticed on Google Hangouts some update made the cam stop working.

When I run `lsusb`, this is the result:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b2e1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

On /dev I see this:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video      81,   0 Mar  5 00:52 video0
```

Also this:

```
 ~ $ ls /dev/v4l/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Mar  5 00:52 usb-Vimicro_Corp._Lenovo_EasyCamera-video-index0 -> ../../video0
```

So, now I test something like VLC to "Open Capture Device". The webcam turns on, but there's no image. Same thing on Skype, I test the video and the cam turns on, but no image. At some point, the camera disappears from lsusb and I can't see it there anymore.

I tested Ubuntu 12.10 from a live USB and the camera works perfectly from there, so it's not a hardware issue, but a software issue. I even tried to run Skype as a root user to test if this was a change in permissions issue, but it still doesn't work.

I have no clue as to how to debug this issue, or find whatever update or installation made it stop working.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user and use your webcam there?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Booting with linux-image-3.5.0-23 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a similar issue on a Thinkpad T430u that I was able to fix by booting to an older kernel.  It sounds like this could be the same issue since the live USB is probably running an older kernel.  I just posted an answer to a similar question, so instead of retyping the whole thing, see here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/264461/18665

If this fixes your issue, please file a bug report or comment on the one I linked to in that answer so the developers know this affects Ubuntu 12.10 as well.  Hopefully if enough people report this bug it should get fixed soon.

Comment: Booting back with linux-image-3.5.0-23 made it work, so yeah, it's a bug in the kernel probably. Thanks for your answer! I've added my comments on the launchpad bug report.