# HP Truevision webcam not working in 12.10

Tags: webcam

I have a laptop with an HP Truevision built-in webcam that is not working under Ubuntu 12.10. Not in Skype, not in Google Hangouts. It used to work on 12.04LTS, but then stopped working after an update.

I upgraded to 12.10 hoping that it would help, but it's still down, even though it worked fine from the Live-USB (!) and I could take my picture with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting to an older kernel. On a number of webcams, all the kernels after 3.5.0-23 had this problem.

Solution is posted here: [integrated webcam issues lenovo t430u ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260338/integrated-webcam-issues-lenovo-t430u-ubuntu-12-10/264461#264461)

Also accounted for here: [12.10: Webcam stopped working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264193/12-10-webcam-stopped-working-after-update)

If this is the problem then please add your name to bug report.