# Webcam on Lenovo U310 has no video

Tags: 12.10, video, webcam, lenovo

I've bought a Lenovo U310, installed Ubuntu 12.10 and wanted to use the internal webcam with Skype and Google Hangout. But I cannot get any video signal out of it. Other apps like cheese can. Audio or an external webcam work fine. Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to kernel 3.5.0-26-generic, which came as a normal system update, fixed the problem. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the webcams on several Lenovo models have stopped working due to a recent kernel update.  Try the solution posted here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/264461/18665

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yesterday I've upgraded my kernel to 3.5.0-26-generic, which came as a normal system update. Now the webcam works fine :).