# Webcam Install not listed by lsusb

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, webcam, acer

Hallo I have a new Acer V5-573g and Ubuntu 12.04

I am trying to install the webcam but if I use the Command:

```
sudo lsusb
```

I get these results:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What should I do?
I dont know how to identify my webcam.

Comment: My next step was to update my Bios from the Acer Website and i run the application on my windows 7 partition. now i get these Results:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I Found the solution my self :)

I went to http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/drivers

Downloaded the BIOS Update installed it under Windows (I have a dualboot with win7 and Ubuntu)

after updating i could not start the computer Because of this error:

```
Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed
```

Solution was entering BIOS (F2) and choose legacy instead of UEFI

now my Webcam is listed and is working just fine bluetooth is also working now.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
**Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3f6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd** 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Solution in German/ Lösung auf deutsch

Habe die Lösung herausgefunden:

einfach ein Bios Update durchführen: http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/drivers

danch daruaf achten das der richtige modus im bios eingestellt ist (Lagacy oder UEFI) sonst startet der PC nicht.

Danach wurde die Webcam angezeigt und funktionierte automatisch außerdem funktioniert bluetooth jetzt auch.